# Multiple wireless networks, same SSID, different 802.11 standards

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I've heard that you can have multiple wireless APs using the same network SSID, same passkey, and different channels to create what clients will see as one seamless wireless network. Is it problematic if my wireless APs are all using different 802.11 standards? I've got G, draft-N, N, and AC all together.

Comment: Sorry for the drive-by, I'm only here for a sec, but check this out: http://tinyurl.com/3nyvs3w. You have to be clever, because identical frequencies/channels will interfere with each other so you'll want to set the channels manually to be different on each AP. I'd say stick with the one standard N or AC (forget G) and one frequency 5GHz (avoid 2.4GHz if you can). Also the multiple APs need to all connect to the one main router which has the public IP address... the linked article says it all better than I can. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different 802.11 flavors shouldn't be a problem, but don't expect your clients to be smart about it. For example, if you have an AC-capable client in a place where the G AP's signal is highest, the AC client may join that and be stuck doing G rates even when it could have gotten better speeds from a slightly more distant AC AP.

Also, if you have any older clients that can only do 2.4GHz, make sure you've got 2.4GHz coverage everywhere that you need it.